# Four blocks in one line. Use only CSS

Tags: css

Results must be in page 4 black blocks, each block must be 200 pixels wide. Distance between blocks 10 pixels. These blocks draw on one line. In layout consider adaptability, ie relatively screen resolution blocks can be a single line 3, 2 or 1.

Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you have to add `display: inline-block` to childs that blocks to be on a line (if the size of the screen is wide enough), else if the size of the screen shrinks, the blocks will go in 2 lines and so on.
[Source](http://jsfiddle.net/sbfxath4/) on jsfiddle

```css
.main-block{
   
}

.child-block {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: black;
    width:200px;
    height:50px;

    margin:5px
}
```

```html
<div class="main-block">
    <div class="child-block">
    </div>
    <div class="child-block">
    </div>
    <div class="child-block">
    </div>
    <div class="child-block">
    </div>
</div>
```

**[v]** 4 black blocks

**[v]** each block must be 200 pixels wide

**[v]** Distance between blocks 10 pixels.

**[v]** These blocks draw on one line.

**[v]** In layout consider adaptability, ie relatively screen resolution blocks can be a single line 3, 2 or 1.

Comment: This mean, blocks must be relative to screen, if 4 block can not fit to screen, block must be on 2 lines. 3 in first line, 1 in second line, and etc

Comment: @dev.nikolaz how about you try something and post a good problem where you are stuck. This is definitely not a homework site :)